# Wordpress metabox: how to get value of field with multiple values?

Tags: php, wordpress

im using this Wordpress Metabox framework: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html

here is the code

```
array(
        'name' => '<strong>Robots Meta</strong>',           
        'desc' => '',                           
        'id' => $prefix . 'robot',               
        'type' => 'radio',                       
        'options' => array(                       
            'if' => 'index, follow',
            'in' => 'index, nofollow',
            'nf' => 'noindex, follow',
            'nn' => 'noindex, nofollow'
        ),       
    ),
```

how do i call the value of each of the radio values in the template?

i tried doing this but it only checks if it is set or not:

```
$metas = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'hiro_robot', false);


foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    echo $meta;
}


if (in_array($val, $metas)) {
    echo "$val is set";
} else {
    echo "$val is not set";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use a short helper function for grabbing meta values.

```
function c3m_get_field($key, $echo = FALSE) {
global $post;
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
if ($echo == FALSE) return $custom_field;
echo $custom_field;
}
```

When using this anytime you want to echo the value of a meta key you can use:

```
c3m_get_field('key', TRUE);
```

If you want to return the value:

```
c3m_get_field('key', FALSE);
```

Also in your answer you don't need to use the `get_the_ID()` function just use `$post->ID`

Answer (score 0):

here i figured it out myself, here it goes like this:

```
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'hiro_robot', true); 

if (is_page() || is_single() && $meta == 'if')
echo '<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />'."\n";

elseif (is_page() || is_single() && $meta == 'in')
echo '<meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow" />'."\n";

elseif (is_page() || is_single() && $meta == 'nf')
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />'."\n";

elseif (is_page() || is_single() && $meta == 'nn')
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />'."\n";
```